# How to deduce nesting class template type from typedef composition?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to define a type from an *typedef alias* for a specialized class template. Using the same (but unknown) class template type and modifying the contained type.

*How to deduce the class template type of the alias?*

I tried using template template parameters [`$ clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -pedantic`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jsfUz8WrOlgPJV48):

```
// ----------------------
// third-party header file; may not be modified

template<typename V>
struct UnknownContainer
{
    V m;
};

typedef UnknownContainer<int> KnownAlias;

// ----------------------
// my file (includes third-party header)
// only knows KnownAlias, not UnknownContainer

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>

template< template <typename> class C >
using MakeConstValueType = C< const int >;

typedef MakeConstValueType<KnownAlias> MyContainer;

// example usage

void foo(const MyContainer& c)
{
    std::cout << "value = " << c.m << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    MyContainer c { 42 };
    foo(c);
}
```

But I get this error:

```sh
prog.cc:23:28: error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
typedef MakeConstValueType<KnownAlias> MyContainer;
                           ^
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doable, but you have to take stock of the error. You wrote a template accept as an argument another template, but you pass it a concrete type. That's a mismatch. Templates aren't types, but recipes for creating them. You can use partial template specialization to recognize when your meta-function is given a type that's generated from a template, but that will require us to use a class template to specialize over.

Over all, it can look like this

```
template<class Container, typename NewValT> struct MakeConstValueTypeHelper;

template< template <typename> class C, typename ValueT, typename NewValT>
struct MakeConstValueTypeHelper<C<ValueT>, NewValT> {
    using type = C<NewValT>;
};

template< class C >
using MakeConstValueType = typename MakeConstValueTypeHelper<C, const int>::type;
```

Now the template parameter matches the argument you intend to give it. The partial specialization unfolds the type into its components, and does the transformation you are after.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It took me a little to comprehend it. I like the "trick" with the partial template specialization. When [applying](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5nrVDb50xgT3l3tS) your solution I removed the `NewValT` template parameter and replaced it with `std::add_const_t< ValueT >` in the `type` alias definition.